# Crear un algoritmo de la suma de dos números aleatorios

Tags: python

no soy muy buen en python y me dejaron Crear un algoritmo de la suma de dos números aleatorios menores a 100 y mayores de 10.
a.  Ejemplo: 45+15=60

¿me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Inténtalo, prueba, revisa qué errores te salen al intentarlo, tráelos junto con tu código, edita la pregunta incluyendo todo esto y con mucho gusto te ayudamos a revisarlo. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En este caso necesitas importar la libreria `random`

```
import random

print(random.randint(10, 100))
```

Usando el metodo randint consigues numeros enteros aleatorios, y de parametros acepta dos numeros que por logico serian el minimo y el maximo. En el caso que quieres hacer tu puedes hacer esto

```
import random

print(random.randint(10, 100) + random.randint(10, 100))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

A ver si esto te sirve:

```
from random import randrange

numero1 = (randrange(10,100))
numero2 = (randrange(10,100))

print (numero1,"+",numero2,"=",numero1+numero2)
```

En el `print` lo ideal sería ver los números `random` que te va a sumar, si no lo necesitas puedes realizar directamente lo siguiente `print (numero1+numero2)`

Comment: Si bien _tratas_ de ayudar al OP, procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad y/o en donde no se demuestre lo que se ha intentado: lee [answer].

Comment: Si hacemos el trabajo por OP, el no aprendera a hacerlas por si mismo.

Comment: muchas gracias  me ayudo a comprender un poco mas

Answer (score -1):

Primero debemos importar la libreria **random** y utilizamos su funcion **randint** que nos pide 2 parametros de tipo entero, el primero hace referencia al valor minimo aleatorio y el ultimo hace referencia al valor maximo aleatorio, teniendo asi que el programa seleccionara un numero aleatorio entre el valor minimo y el valor maximo (incluyendo ambos). Luego almacenamos en una variable que en este caso llame **suma** la suma del primer valor escogido aleatoriamente y el segundo valor escogido aleatoriamente. Por ultimo mostramos por consola los dos valores escogidos y la suma de esto. Espero te sea util

```
import random

numero_1 = random.randint(10,100)
numero_2 = random.randint(10,100)
suma = numero_1 + numero_2
print(f"El numero 1 es: {numero_1}\nEl numero 2 es: {numero_2} \nLa suma es: {suma}")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias fue de mucha ayuda